# Is it possible to pause state machine until SQS message consumed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

State machine [can](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-sqs.html) send sqs message. Also [Wait for Callback](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-service-integrations.html) is supported for sqs. But what exactly support is? State machine pauses until message is sent or waits until message will be consumed?

Answer (score 0):

> State machine pauses until message is sent or waits until message will be consumed?

Neither of this. According to this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token).

> The task will pause until it receives that task token back with a SendTaskSuccess or SendTaskFailure call.